# Benefits and drawbacks of using client side frameworks

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, backbone.js, ember.js

We are starting to use JavaScript more and more in our projects to improve the client experience. Currently most of our site posts back for just about every user interaction. We mostly use JQuery and plain JavaScript on the client with Asp.Net on the server. Things have started getting very messy and unorganized on the client.

I was thinking of choosing a client side framework like Knockout, Angular, Ember or Backbone to introduce some kind of structure to our client side development. Especially now when it is still early and the JavaScript isn’t a complete disaster. I was wondering if there are any drawbacks from using a client side framework and if we should just stick to using JQuery. Also what would we gain from using a client framework?

Comment: Err, you gain the same things that you gain from using *any* framework. You say yourself that your jQuery isn't yet a "complete disaster", so you presumably know that a framework is at least a partial solution to this problem. What more do you want to know?

Comment: It depends on you own requirement. So , you better dig up INTERNET to find a viable solution for your own good.

Comment: My two cents, [**Rich javascript application - Steven Sanderson**](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2012/08/01/rich-javascript-applications-the-seven-frameworks-throne-of-js-2012/) also [**The future of javascript**](http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2013/08/29/the-future-is-js-on-the-client-and-i-wont-be-left-behind/)

Comment: -1: In it's current format, this question is too broad for a Q&A format and leads to discussion.

Comment: Same of using hammer to nail down - you can build house or just hurt your fingers. If u use proper framework for appropriate task you unlikely face any drawback, otherwise you will have your fingers hurt. Anyway question look like to be off-topic ask opinion ask. Better google for answers

Comment: I am a little confused here as I did check the site to see if my question was appropriate. [Benefits+and+drawbacks](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Benefits+and+drawbacks). I was simply trying to draw on the experience of other developers that have dealt with similar scenarios.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recent Javascript frameworks can help architect your code so that it is modular (therefore reusable), DRY, readable, performant and secure and most importantly cohesive as well as easy to understand. jQuery is not a framework, so it doesn't help in these regards. We've all seen the typical bulks of jQuery spaghetti code. This isn't jQuery's fault - it's the fault of developers that don't know how to architect code. However, if the devs did know how to architect code, they would end up writing some kind of minimal "framework" to provide the foundation (architecture, etc).

The problem here is that we should not forget that jQuery code slowly and steadily becomes so bulky and unstructured that you'll probably run from editing it. However, using any of the frameworks that you listed out [and some more of them] will definitely give you some added advantages.

Here are some things that modern frameworks are providing:

> Templating
>
> Data-binding
>
> routing (single page app)
>
> clean, modular, reusable architecture
>
> security
>
> additional functions/features for convenience

Hence in short and sweet manner, go for one of the frameworks that you listed [Personally, i use and prefer AngularJs]

Answer (score 4):

If you organize your code really well, just javascript and jQuery can be super powerful.

Angular seems to be the framework that everyone loves these days, but it's got a steep learning curve. (in my opinion)

No matter what you're using I'd follow these principles:

1. Keep your code in .js files and out of your views.
2. Put everything inside an object and out of global scope.

   myApplication = {}

Then you can put all your functions grouped inside objects so they're organized:

```
myApplication = {
  navigation: {
    loadNavigation: function() {
      // do something;
    },
    hideNavigation: function() {
      // do something;
    }
  },

  otherObject: {
    otherFunction: function() {
      // etc
    }
  },

  init: function() {
    myApplication.navigation.loadNavigation();
    // other functions to run;
  }
};
```

Then you can just load your application code with one:

```
$().ready(function() {
  myApplication.init();
}
```

I find this pattern lets me build large applications without things getting messy.